# Comparing FPGA with ASIC design

Tags: fpga

I have a fundamental question. I produced some FPGA image for some media application and 
now I would like to compare my results to the ones of ASIC implementation of the same algorithm in terms of performance & area. I have heard such a comparasion does not make sense since it is somewhat comparing apples and oranges. But I have heard about the Gate-equivalence metric, cant I use this for comparison reasons?

Thanks

Comment: One of the few papers I seen on this topic is: [Measuring the gap between FPGAs and ASICs](http://www.eecg.toronto.edu/~jayar/pubs/kuon/kuonfpga06.pdf). Its an interesting read and illustrates the difficulty in comparing the two different technologies.

Answer (score 1):

As has been pointed out, gate equivalents are only a rough guesstimate and not all that accurate for determining area in an ASIC.  There are different of ways you can go about finding out how your design would perform (and cost) in an ASIC.  You likely used an HDL (VHDL or Verilog) to implement your design.  If you have access to a synthesis tool like Synopsys' Design Compiler (DC) you can use that with one of the supplied ASIC vendor libraries to determine area.  You can also use it to generate a post-synthesis, gate-level netlist that you can use in simulation to determine performance.  DC will also give you information about critical path timing, etc. that can be used to calculate performance as well.

However, DC is a very expensive product and you likely used FPGA vendor supplied tools to synthesize your HDL design.  You could approach an ASIC vendor and ask them to analyze your design to determine size & performance (they would likely use DC - you'd have to be willing to hand your HDL over to them).  They may be inclined to do this in order to win your business.  But as has been pointed out ASIC NREs are very expensive, so unless you have a high-volume product it probably doesn't make sense to move your design to an ASIC.

Answer (score 0):

The gate equivalence metric might get you to within an order of magnitude - if that's good enough for you?  The problem is that a 4-input LUT can implement a single AND gate, or a complex 4-input function representing several gates.  Or (in a Xilinx chip) it can be a shift register with 16 bits of memory in it.  And it has a flipflop attached to its output (with attendant control signals and the like.... another few gates).  And if you've used Block memory or the DSP blocks, they are even harder to quantify.

When you say you want to compare performance and area, do you really mean "cost"? Is this a potential product with millions of units sold, or "just" a few 10s of thousands?  ASIC NRE is big!

You can optimise your FPGA design for cost as well, which might be good enough, depending on your volumes.  For example, an image-processing design done in a traditional fashion can be 10x bigger than one designed for seriously small FPGA usage, with similar application performance... if you know what you're doing :)